# R ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval

Tags: r, ggplot2, powerbi

I know there are many posts already on this topic most of them are attributed by the variable or data not being mapped in the ggplot2. However in my case I do have it and I use it further on in my ggplot2.

My source is a dataset from Power BI

```
Throughput  Label  ThroughputAgegroup       
621 Assess reimbursement 1-3 Maanden
1201 Assess reimbursement 3-6 Maanden
105 Authorized 3-6 Maanden
150 Cancelled 1-3 Maanden
771 Cancelled 3-6 Maanden
4215 Closed 0-14 Dagen
57098 Closed 1-3 Maanden
14180 Closed 15-30 Dagen
26631 Closed 3-6 Maanden
14813 Closed 6-12 Maanden
52347 Closed Groter dan 12 maanden
1600 Dispatched 1-3 Maanden
58 Dispatched 15-30 Dagen
394 Dispatched 3-6 Maanden
110 Intake 1-3 Maanden
818 Ready for closure 1-3 Maanden
112 Ready for closure 3-6 Maanden
```

My R plot:

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(x=`ThroughputAgegroup`, y=`Label`))+ 
geom_point(size=10, alpha=0.5,aes(colour=`Label`), na.rm = TRUE) +
geom_text(aes(label=`Throughput`), size=3) + 
scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

I want to make the size dependant on`Throughput`.

When I try to run this:

```
ggplot(dataset, aes(x=`ThroughputAgegroup`, y=`Label`))+ 
geom_point(aes(size=`Throughput`), alpha=0.5,aes(colour=`Label`)) +
geom_text(aes(label=`Throughput`), size=3) + 
scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

I get prompted with:
Error: **ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class uneval**

But I just don't get it why it can't get to the class?

Comment: You have multiple aesthetics inside `geom_points()`. It only works with a single `aes()`.

Comment: @nde How did my suggestion work out for you?

Answer (score 0):

As the commentes have already pointed out, there is a problem with:

```
geom_point(aes(size=`Throughput`), alpha=0.5,aes(colour=`Label`))
```

This is what you need to replace it with to make the size dependant onThroughput:

```
size1 <- dataset$Throughput
geom_point(size=size1, alpha=0.5,aes(colour=`Label`), na.rm = TRUE)
```

But your challenges don't stop there. Let me show you what I mean.

---

It's great that you've provided a datasample. But it's not so great that the sample data is messy and not very easy to pick up since your separator seems to be a `space` and you've got several spaces in your variables. If you use this instead:

```
Throughput,Label,ThroughputAgegroup
621,Assess reimbursement,1-3 Maanden
1201,Assess reimbursement,3-6 Maanden
105,Authorized,3-6 Maanden
150,Cancelled,1-3 Maanden
771,Cancelled,3-6 Maanden
4215,Closed,0-14 Dagen
57098,Closed,1-3 Maanden
14180,Closed,15-30 Dagen
26631,Closed,3-6 Maanden
14813,Closed,6-12 Maanden
52347,Closed,Groter dan 12 maanden
1600,Dispatched,1-3 Maanden
58,Dispatched,15-30 Dagen
394,Dispatched,3-6 Maanden
110,Intake,1-3 Maanden
818,Ready for closure,1-3 Maanden
112,Ready for closure,3-6 Maanden
```

You can easily copy it and import it in R using `dataset <- read.delim("clipboard", sep = ",")`

And now, the charts:

**Plot 1** - your original chart:

[image]

**Plot 3** - your chart with `geom_point(size=size1, alpha=0.5,aes(colour=`Label`), na.rm = TRUE)`

[image]

I'm betting that this is not what you're looking for. What happens here is that you have a some values that are low, and a a few other values that are comparably VERY high, so that the chart is dominated by the latter. But don't despair, you can use the log of the series instead:

```
# my suggestion
size2 <- log(dataset$Throughput)
ggplot(dataset, aes(x=`ThroughputAgegroup`, y=`Label`))+ 
  geom_point(size=size2, alpha=0.5,aes(colour=`Label`), na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_text(aes(label=`Throughput`), size=3) + 
  scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

**Plot** - bubble sizes = `log(dataset$Throughput)`

[image]

I think that looks OK! But you could also do further adjustments using `log(dataset$Throughput)^1.6` and adjust the last part `^1.6` , like this:

[image]

If you're still not quite happy, take a look at the superb docs at [ggplot2.tidyverse.org](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_point.html) and take it from there.

Heres the whole code for an easy copy&paste:

```
library(ggplot2)

# rm(list=ls())
# dataset <- read.delim("clipboard", sep = ",")

# original
ggplot(dataset, aes(x=`ThroughputAgegroup`, y=`Label`))+ 
  geom_point(size=10, alpha=0.5,aes(colour=`Label`), na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_text(aes(label=`Throughput`), size=3) + 
  scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1")

# my suggestion
size2 <- log(dataset$Throughput)
size3 <- log(dataset$Throughput)^1.6
ggplot(dataset, aes(x=`ThroughputAgegroup`, y=`Label`))+ 
  geom_point(size=size3, alpha=0.5,aes(colour=`Label`), na.rm = TRUE) +
  geom_text(aes(label=`Throughput`), size=3) + 
  scale_colour_brewer(palette="Set1")
```